# Hack language - Set intersection

Tags: hacklang

The Hack `Set` has a `difference` method but I don't see a method called `intersect` or any similar one.

How to get an intersection of two sets?

```
$set1 = Set { 'a', 'x' };
$set2 = Set { 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y' };
$intersection = ??? // Set { 'x' }
```

Docs: https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/reference/class/HH.Set/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why that function doesn't exist, but you can put this code in some utility function:

```
  $intersection = Set {};
  foreach ($other as $v) {
    if ($set->contains($v)) {
      $intersection->add($v);
    }
  }
```

Additionally, you can add a check so you iterate the smaller set.

OR, if you like one liners, this also works :)

```
$set1->filter($x ==> $set2->contains($x))
```

Comment: 6 years later, is it still the case the function does not exist?